# Mongodb: Восстановление базы данных

Tags: debian, mongodb

После перезагрузки сервера, обнаружил, что базы данных нет. До этого сервер ужасно лагал. В папке /data/db все же остались файлы базы данных (расширения .1, .2, .3, .4, .ns). Можно ли с помощью них восстановить базу данных? Или может неправильно запускал?

```
mongod --repair
mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log --nojournal --bind_ip 127.0.0.1
```

Команда **show dbs** возвращает local 0.078GB

Answer (score 1):

В сайте другого проекта StackExchenge - ServerFault [есть ответ на ваш вопрос](https://serverfault.com/questions/439658/is-it-possible-to-recover-mongodb-databases-from-ns-and-0-1-files)

Вольный перевод:

> Файлы *.ns, *.0, *.1 и т.д. - это сами файлы данных. Если вы
>   запустите `mongod` со значением флага `--dbpath`, указывающим на эту
>   папку, или если вы переместите их куда угодно и так же укажете новый
>   путь, `mongod` корректно их подхватит и прочитает

Другими словами: **да, вы можете на основе этих файлов восстановить базу, явно указав эту папку в качестве текущей папки БД**. Возможно придется лишь удалить `mongod.lock` - триггер, сигнализирующий, что данная папка используется каким-то экземпляром `mongod`, и остающимся неудаленным при его некорректном завершении.